# Avoid inverting covariance matrix A in $V^TA^{-1}V$

Tags: linear-algebra, python

I have a formula $Qy = v^TA^{-1}v$ with vector $v = y - \xi$ for a fixed $\xi$, and covariance matrix $A$ (see the formula for $Qy$ at the bottom of page 21 in [appendix A.2](https://epublications.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1225&context=mscs_fac)). I know that for reasons of speed and accuracy, it's generally good to avoid inverting matrices (see [here](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/12/09/matrix-inversion/) for example). Is there any way to avoid that when computing $Qy$ here?

I currently find the inverse of $A$ by using $AX=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, and a solver and solving for $X$. I'm hoping there's some way to rearrange things that avoids the need for even this method of inversion. In particular, I'm interested in methods likely to perform better when implemented in numpy/scipy (the $AX=I$ approach uses [`cho_solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.cho_solve.html) and isn't particularly fast.).

Comment: Covariance matrices are symmetric and positive semi-definite. Maybe some time could be gained from diagonalizing it, or some similar decomposition, compared to directly solving for the inverse?

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm already using `cho_solve` which expects a Cholesky factorization for $A$ instead of a generic solver. I edited my question slightly so that it doesn't suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless $V$ has some special relationship to $A$ (as noted by Arthur) I don't think there's anything better than solving $AX = V$ and then setting $Q = V^TX$.

This is slightly faster than your current approach (since you only need to solve one linear system instead of $n$).

Comment: Thanks! This cut the runtime down to around 1/3 of what it had been with my original approach.